# Applying the same factor levels to multiple variables in an R data frame

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset that includes 16 questions where the response set is identical (Yes, No, Unknown or Missing). I am processing the data using R and I want to turn each of the variables into a factor. For a single variable, I could use the following construction:

```
df <- read.csv("thedata.csv")
df$q1 <- factor(x=df$q1,levels=c(-9,0,1),
                        labels=c("Unknown or Missing","No","Yes))
```

I'd like to avoid typing that 16 times. I could do it with a `for()`, but I was wondering if there is a clearer, more R way to do it. Some sample data:

```
structure(list(q1 = c(0, 0, 0, -9, 0), q2 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
               q3 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), q4 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
               q5 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), q6 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
               q7 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), q8 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
               q9 = c(1, 0, -9, 1, 0), q10 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
               q11 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0), q12 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
               q13 = c(1, -9, 1, 0, 0), q14 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
               q15 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0), q16 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)),
               .Names = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7",
                          "q8", "q9", "q10", "q11", "q12", "q13",
                          "q14", "q15", "q16"),
               row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
df[] <- lapply(df, factor, 
              levels=c(-9, 0, 1), 
              labels = c("Unknown or Missing", "No", "Yes"))
str(df)
```

Likely to be faster than apply or sapply which need data.frame to reform/reclass those results. The trick here is that using `[]` on the LHS of the assignment preserves the structure of the target (because R "knows" what its class and dimensions are, and the need for `data.frame` on the list from `lapply` is not needed. If you had wanted to do this only with selected columns you could do this:

```
 df[colnums] <- lapply(df[colnums], factor, 
              levels=c(-9, 0, 1), 
              labels = c("Unknown or Missing", "No", "Yes"))
 str(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

An R base solution using `apply`

```
 data.frame(apply(df, 2, factor, 
                 levels=c(-9, 0, 1), 
                 labels = c("Unknown or Missing", "No", "Yes")))
```

Using `sapply`

```
data.frame(sapply(df, factor, levels=c(-9, 0, 1), 
         labels = c("Unknown or Missing", "No", "Yes")))
```

Comment: Beware: apply always converts it's input into a matrix