# Using lapply to label the values of specific variables

Tags: r, lapply

I would like to use `lapply` to label the values of specific variables. I have found an example that gets me close ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484236/applying-the-same-factor-levels-to-multiple-variables-in-an-r-data-frame)), but I can't get it to work for only certain variables in the data set.

Working example:

```
df1 <- tribble(
 ~var1, ~var2, ~var3, ~var4,
 "1",   "1",   "1", "a",
 "2",   "2",   "2", "b",
 "3",   "3",   "3", "c"
)
```

Here is the code that seems like it should work, but doesn't:

```
df1["var1", "var2"] <- lapply(df1["var1", "var2"], factor,
                          levels=c(1, 
                                   2, 
                                   3), 
                          labels = c("Agree", 
                                     "Neither Agree/Disagree", 
                                     "Disagree"))
```

The code runs, but give the following output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  var1  var2  var3  var4
* <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1     1     1     a
2     2     2     2     b
3     3     3     3     c
4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

If I try with just one variable, it works:

```
df1["var1"] <- lapply(df1["var1"], factor,
                          levels=c(1, 
                                2, 
                                3), 
                          labels = c("Agree", 
                                  "Neither Agree/Disagree", 
                                  "Disagree"))
```

It gives the following output (which is correct):

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
                    var1  var2  var3  var4
                  <fctr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1                  Agree     1     1     a
2 Neither Agree/Disagree     2     2     b
3               Disagree     3     3     c
```

I have tried a lot of different ways to change the code to get it to work, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: just use `df1[c("var1","var2")]` or `df1[1:2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is arising because you're trying to subset your `data.frame` incorrectly.

In a `data.frame` or `tbl`, extracting using `[` works in a couple of ways.

- Since the data is in a `matrix`-like rectangular form, you can use a `[row, column]` approach to get specific values. For example to get a single value, you can do something like `df1[2, 1]`.
- Since a `tbl`/`data.frame` is a special type of `list`, if you don't supply a comma, it assumes you want the entire list element.

Thus, when you did `["var1", "var2"]`, it went into `matrix` subsetting mode and was looking for a row named "var1", which it couldn't find, so it inserted a row of `NA` values in your dataset.

Here's a small set of examples for you to experiment with.

- Get rows 1:4 and columns 1:4

  ```
  df <- mtcars[1:4, 1:4]
  df
  #                 mpg cyl disp  hp
  # Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110
  # Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110
  # Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93
  # Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110
  ```
- Extract a single value using a `[row, column]` approach

  ```
  df["Mazda RX4", "mpg"]  # [row, column]
  # [1] 21
  ```
- Check whether a `data.frame` is a `list`

  ```
  is.list(df)
  # [1] TRUE
  ```
- Convert a `data.frame` to a `list` and try to extract using `[row, column]`.

  ```
  L <- unclass(df)
  L["Mazda RX4", "mpg"]   # A list doesn't have `dim`s.
  # Error in L["Mazda RX4", "mpg"] : incorrect number of dimensions
  ```
- Providing just one value to extract from a `data.frame` or a `list`

  ```
  df["mpg"]               # Treats it as asking for a single value from a list
  #                 mpg
  # Mazda RX4      21.0
  # Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0
  # Datsun 710     22.8
  # Hornet 4 Drive 21.4

  L["mpg"]
  # $mpg
  # [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4
  ```
- Providing a vector of values to extract

  ```
  df[c("mpg", "hp")]
  #                 mpg  hp
  # Mazda RX4      21.0 110
  # Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0 110
  # Datsun 710     22.8  93
  # Hornet 4 Drive 21.4 110

  L[c("mpg", "hp")]
  # $mpg
  # [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4
  # 
  # $hp
  # [1] 110 110  93 110
  ```
- Since a `data.frame` is a special type of `list` with `dim`s, using an empty `[, vals]` would work

  ```
  df[, c("mpg", "hp")]
  #                 mpg  hp
  # Mazda RX4      21.0 110
  # Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0 110
  # Datsun 710     22.8  93
  # Hornet 4 Drive 21.4 110
  ```
- Looking for a row that is not there would return `NA`s

  ```
  df["not here", ]
  #    mpg cyl disp hp
  # NA  NA  NA   NA NA
  ```

---

Keeping those details in mind, your best approach is to just use (as suggested in [@www's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47935230/1270695):

```
df1[c("var1", "var2")]
```

Comment: Thanks so much @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1! This is the kind of answer that helps me better understand R and the logic behind the coding. Much appreciated.

Comment: Such a clear and succinct answer!

Answer (score 2):

You were close. We need `df1[c("var1", "var2")]` to specify columns.

```
df1[c("var1", "var2")] <- lapply(df1[c("var1", "var2")], factor,
                              levels=c("1", 
                                       "2", 
                                       "3"), 
                              labels = c("Agree", 
                                         "Neither Agree/Disagree", 
                                         "Disagree"))
df1
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#                     var1                   var2  var3  var4
#                   <fctr>                 <fctr> <chr> <chr>
# 1                  Agree                  Agree     1     a
# 2 Neither Agree/Disagree Neither Agree/Disagree     2     b
# 3               Disagree               Disagree     3     c
```

Comment: Ah, okay. Such a simple thing. I won't make that mistake again. Thanks @www!